# Application doesn't load azure app config feature flag value but loads config values

Tags: c#, azure, azure-app-configuration

I have a Blazor app that I want to use Azure app config.

I've successfully setup getting config values, however it doesn't find my feature flag.

When I inject an IConfiguration and query the value of a config value, like so `Configuration["value"]` the proper data is retrieved.

But when I try and check if my only feature flag is enabled (and it is) the result is always false, which I imagine is because the app can't find the feature flag, not because it's reading the value wrong (passing the name of a non-existant feature flag causes the method to return "false").

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;

namespace OreNoAppu
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy);

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
            services.AddFeatureManagement();
            services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days.You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAzureAppConfiguration();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using BoomiLogReader.Utility;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;

namespace OreNoAppu
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitKeyVault();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                    {
                        var connection = KeyVaultReader.GetSecretValue("AzureAppConfigConnStr");
                        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                            options.Connect(connection).UseFeatureFlags());
                    }).UseStartup<Startup>());

        // Initialises KeyVaultReader, which is used to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault.
        public static void InitKeyVault()
        {
            // N'importe quoi, access to KeyVault and getting of the conn string works fine.
        }
    }
}
```

Code that should be getting the flag:

```
@using Microsoft.FeatureManagement
@inject IFeatureManager featureManager

@if (featureEnabled)
{
    <h1>Yes</h1>
}

@code
{
    bool featureEnabled = true;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        featureEnabled = featureManager.IsEnabledAsync("OreNoFlaggu").Result;
    }
}
```

Debugging, I see that the method call "IsEnabledAsync" returns "false", but there is a "OreNoFlaggu" feature flag in my app config, that the application successfully connects and retrieves config values from, and said flag is enabled.

Any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Tessaract, does your feature flag happen to have a label in your App Config store. If so, please don't forget to pass the label when calling `UseFeatureFlags()` via [`FeatureFlagOptions.Label`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azureappconfiguration.featuremanagement.featureflagoptions.label?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_AzureAppConfiguration_FeatureManagement_FeatureFlagOptions_Label).

Comment: Ay, carumba! Not only is this not mentioned in any of the 3-4 tutorials I read through, I couldn't even find any example or information after reading your answer. Good thing my first guess at pseudocode paid off. Thank you!

Comment: Agreed. The doc could be improved.

Comment: This trick saved me too. On app configuration, I updated my feature flags with the label name "SomeLabelName" and used below code snippet.

.UseFeatureFlags(opt => {
                           opt.Label = "SomeLabelName";
                       });

Thanks @ZhenlanWang